# Keystonejs with Oauth2 has no return

Tags: keystonejs

I am using KeystoneJS and wanna insert the oauth2 codes.

All my Token and Users codes are run very fine; the methods are triggered via console.log. The token is generated successfully.

However, there is no return and finally I receive a timeout in my client:

```
// Setup Route Bindings 
exports = module.exports = function(app) {   
// Oauth2   
var oauth = oauthserver({
             model: require('../models/Client'),
            grants: ['password', 'refresh_token'],
            debug: true   });


// Views
app.get('/', routes.views.index);



  // both routes below can be triggered correctly, but timeout return
  app.all('/oauth/token', oauth.grant());

  app.get('/secret', oauth.authorise(), function (req, res) {
    res.send('Secret area');
  });

};
```

Comment: your question is not very clear. Is your intent to replace Keystone's authentication with OAUTH2 in order to access the Keystone Admin UI or is this solely for your application's routes? Also, which NPM module are you using for OAUTH2? From your code it looks like you're using [node-oauth2-server](https://github.com/thomseddon/node-oauth2-server), but since there no require it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Hi @JME, I am using the node-oauth2-server, and want to insert my /api routes with the oauth2 token protected. I successfully to do it in bare expressjs.  The question is "app.all('/oauth/token', oauth.grant());" doesn't return anything as expected in KeystoneJS route/index.js

Comment: Can you add `models/Client.js` to your question?